# Vertical Chinese text with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, cjk

How can I place vertical Chinese text for some of the text in a document?

- I think the [`CJK`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cjk) package can do this, but with XeTeX one generally uses `xeCJK`.
- I could not find these options in the documentation for the [`xeCJK`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) or [`ctex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctex) packages.

Comment: You could try the sample code at this [ctex discussion thread](http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=65622&highlight=xetex%2B%D6%D0%CE%C4%2B%D6%B1%C5%C5). In general, you'd likely have better luck at the CTEX discussion site with such in-depth CJK typesetting queries.

Comment: See [this thread in CTeX forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=45054) for datailed discussion. I'll provide an example here.

Comment: @LeoLiu Now why didn't my search on ctex turn up that thread?! I remember it but couldn't get at it just now. -_-

Comment: @LianTzeLim: I've no idea. Anyway, it's easy for me to find it out ^_^

Comment: The link to the thread in the CTeX forum has changed, it now is http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=45054

Comment: Related: [What is UpTex / UpLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295414/what-is-uptex-uplatex).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know only some discussion for Chinese. There are some discussions and tools for vertical Japanese, but I know little about it.

I'm sorry that vertical typesetting options are still not available in `xeCJK`. It is indeed in the TODO list, but not urgent at all.

For vertical typesetting, some techniques are needed:

- Rotate the glyphs. It can be obtained by setting the font with special options.
- Rotate the whole paragraph or whole page. Use `\rotatebox` from `graphics` bundle, or use special commands of XeTeX like `pdflscape` package do.
- Use correct vertical punctuations. It is a special OpenType font feature.
- Offset the glyphs a little. Like `CJKvert` package do. We can hack `xeCJK` to do this.
- Some extra tools like [`gezhu`](https://code.google.com/p/gezhu/) package. (not shown in the example below)

A full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\setCJKfamilyfont{songvert}[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{SimSun}

\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}% do not modify the spacing between punctuations
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKsymbol}

\begin{document}

屈原《离骚》曰：
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{-90}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{10em}
\CJKfamily{songvert}\CJKmove
『朝发轫于苍梧兮，\\
夕余至乎县圃。\\
欲少留此灵琐兮，\\
日忽忽其将暮。\\
吾令羲和弭节兮，\\
望崦嵫而勿迫。』
\end{minipage}}}
\end{center}
这里羲和便等于一名马车夫，因为
他是御日的，诗人生怕太阳赶快落了，就叫羲和慢一点走。不过话经我
一翻译，显得淘气一点，原文只是一个高贵的身分，另外不表现着什么
个性了。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i could not get this to work with xetex 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian). i just copied and pasted what you have above. i made a paste here: http://pastebin.com/0gnnWmWz

Comment: @magnetar: Just use `xelatex` instead of `xetex` command. It's trivial.

Comment: @LeoLiu: This example works nicely here on TeXShop v. 2.47 on Mac OS 10.8, but I'm sorry to see that it doesn't work with the HAN NOM fonts; only with commercial Chinese fonts that I have, such as SimSun. Is there something I can do to make HAN NOM work, or is the problem irremediable at this point?

Comment: @brannerchinese: I've no good idea.

Comment: @LeoLiu: In my case, it was necessary to add
`RawFeature={vertical;+vert}`, that is,
`\setCJKfamilyfont{songvert}[RawFeature={vertical;+vert},Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{SimSun}`
in order to obtain correct vertical text in the minipage,
by using the latest fontspec:
`fontspec.sty    2017/07/23 v2.6c`.
Was the fontspec changed?

Comment: @LeoLiu: In the above, it was enough that
`RawFeature={vertical}`.

Comment: With fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i and xeCJK 2020/06/06 v3.8.4, `Vertical=RotatedGlyphs` does not work and `RawFeature={vertical}` works fine.