# rotating vs lscape vs pdflscape

Tags: rotating, pdflscape, lscape

I'm asking this looking for the *`ultimate`* answer.  What are the main differences between the three of them?  When should I use anyone in particular?

I know there is this question:  [Should I prefer {pdflscape} over [pdftex]{lscape}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61365/should-i-prefer-pdflscape-over-pdftexlscape), but it doesn't address the issue with the `rotating` package.

Also, there is this question: [Rotating text by -90 degrees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38593/rotating-text-by-90-degrees)        , but once gain: no reference about the `rotating` package.

Furthermore, I'm trying to get a figure (packages: `graphicx`, `float`, `subcaption`),  and later on a Gantt diagram (packages: `tikz`, `pgfgantt`) on landscape layout.

Which one of the three should I use? What are the advantages of one over the other? (I have already gone through this question: [Rotate Gantt Chart Figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106353/rotate-gantt-chart-figure/106365#106365), but the only answer is with `lscape`).

---

UPDATE: I ran some tests and it seems that when using a `longtable` environment `pdflscape` modifies all the pages along the table, whereas `[pdftex]{lscape}` only modifies the last one.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}  % Uncomment if you want to see the output with [pdftex]{lscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l p{0.8\linewidth}}

WEFAPS          & \hspace{5mm} Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
WHO                 &   \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\
MEMs                &   \hspace{5mm} Micro-Electromechanics\\
BDN                 & \hspace{5mm} Bayesian Dynamic Networks\\
ADL                 & \hspace{5mm} Activities of Daily Life\\
STST                &   \hspace{5mm} Sit-To-Stand Test\\
PPA                 &   \hspace{5mm} Physiological Profile Assessment\\
TUGT                &   \hspace{5mm} Timed Up-and-Go Test\\
DFRAC               & \hspace{5mm} Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
STRATIFY        & \hspace{5mm} Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients\\
USUST               & \hspace{5mm} Unstructured and Unsupervised Test\\
WEFAPS          & \hspace{5mm} Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
WHO                 &   \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\
MEMs                &   \hspace{5mm} Micro-Electromechanics\\
BDN                 & \hspace{5mm} Bayesian Dynamic Networks\\
ADL                 & \hspace{5mm} Activities of Daily Life\\
STST                &   \hspace{5mm} Sit-To-Stand Test\\
PPA                 &   \hspace{5mm} Physiological Profile Assessment\\
TUGT                &   \hspace{5mm} Timed Up-and-Go Test\\
DFRAC               & \hspace{5mm} Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
STRATIFY        & \hspace{5mm} Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients\\
USUST               & \hspace{5mm} Unstructured and Unsupervised Test\\
WEFAPS          & \hspace{5mm} Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
WHO                 &   \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\
MEMs                &   \hspace{5mm} Micro-Electromechanics\\
BDN                 & \hspace{5mm} Bayesian Dynamic Networks\\
ADL                 & \hspace{5mm} Activities of Daily Life\\
STST                &   \hspace{5mm} Sit-To-Stand Test\\
PPA                 &   \hspace{5mm} Physiological Profile Assessment\\
TUGT                &   \hspace{5mm} Timed Up-and-Go Test\\
DFRAC               & \hspace{5mm} Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
STRATIFY        & \hspace{5mm} Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients\\
USUST               & \hspace{5mm} Unstructured and Unsupervised Test\\
WEFAPS          & \hspace{5mm} Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
WHO                 &   \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\
MEMs                &   \hspace{5mm} Micro-Electromechanics\\
BDN                 & \hspace{5mm} Bayesian Dynamic Networks\\
ADL                 & \hspace{5mm} Activities of Daily Life\\
STST                &   \hspace{5mm} Sit-To-Stand Test\\
PPA                 &   \hspace{5mm} Physiological Profile Assessment\\
TUGT                &   \hspace{5mm} Timed Up-and-Go Test\\
DFRAC               & \hspace{5mm} Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
STRATIFY        & \hspace{5mm} Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients\\
USUST               & \hspace{5mm} Unstructured and Unsupervised Test\\
WEFAPS          & \hspace{5mm} Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
WHO                 &   \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\
MEMs                &   \hspace{5mm} Micro-Electromechanics\\
BDN                 & \hspace{5mm} Bayesian Dynamic Networks\\
ADL                 & \hspace{5mm} Activities of Daily Life\\
STST                &   \hspace{5mm} Sit-To-Stand Test\\
PPA                 &   \hspace{5mm} Physiological Profile Assessment\\
TUGT                &   \hspace{5mm} Timed Up-and-Go Test\\
DFRAC               & \hspace{5mm} Demura's Fall Risk Assessment Chart\\
STRATIFY        & \hspace{5mm} Saint Thomas's Risk Assessment Tool in Falling Elderly Inpatients\\
USUST               & \hspace{5mm} Unstructured and Unsupervised Test\\


\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to add a MWE demonstrating the update ? code speaks better :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`lscape` and `pdflscape` is the same, the first for using `latex` the second for `pdflatex`. If your image needs more or less the total `\textheigth` as width then use the `landscape` environment, defined by these packages. If the image is much more smaller and doesn't need the whole page then use `\rotatebox` or the environment `turn` or `\hvfloat` from the package of the same name if you also need a caption and, of course, no page break.

You do not need all those `\hspace`:

```
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape} 
[ ... ]
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l @{\hspace{5mm}} p{0.8\linewidth}}

WEFAPS          &  Wearable Fall Assessment \& Prediction System\\
```

and viewing the *pdf* output with `lscape` is identical to the one with `pdflscape`

Comment: I was running some tests and I saw that `pdflscape` rotates all pages from a `longtable`, whereas `[pdftex]lscape` only the last one

Comment: textheigth-->text height

Comment: @MarioS.E.: I suppose you viewed the `dvi` output. View only the pdf one: `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. And you do not need the `[pdftex]` option.

Comment: Why did't you suggest the package `hvfloat` ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: indeed, a good question :-)

Comment: @Herbert, no, I'm using TeXnicCenter with LaTeX--> PDF, my pdf viewer is Adobe Reader XI and I continue to get the same result: [pdftex]{lscape} only shows rotated the last page.  All of them are in landscape, but rotated for you to see it without turning your head just the last one

Comment: @MarioS.E.: that is a problem with GhostScript. Use `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None <file>.ps` or `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=#None <file>.ps` if you are under Windows. And do _not_ use the option `[pdftex]` it is not needed.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks! :).  So, for landscape purposes with pdftex, lscape and pdflscape are the same... when can they be different and benefitial to use one or another?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: Again: if you run `pdflatex` then `pdflscape` and if you run `latex` then `lscape`