# A problem with cjkutf8 and pst-eucl

Tags: pstricks, cjk, pst-eucl

The following MWE cannot be compiled. You can see the error messages by yourself.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\def\kor#1{%
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}
#1%
\end{CJK}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(7,8)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={\kor{지}},PosAngle=90](3,3){A}
    %\rput(3,3){\kor{웅}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

`PointName` cannot accept CJK characters. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CJK` package defines CJK symbols as macros. So there are some problems in special cases.

Anyway, you can always use this trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\newsavebox\korbox
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}
\begin{pspicture}(7,8)
\sbox\korbox{지}
\pstGeonode[PointName={\usebox\korbox},PosAngle=90](3,3){A}
\sbox\korbox{웅}
\pstGeonode[PointName={\usebox\korbox},PosAngle=90](5,3){B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

BTW, you don't need to use `CJKutf8` package unless you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. And you can use `CJK` environment globally, it's safe.

Comment: what package do I need to allow the characters to flow from top to bottom instead of the normal (flowing from left to right)?

Comment: @Bugbusters: You can't do that. You should rotate the characters and rotate the page. See [Vertical Chinese text with XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38577/vertical-chinese-text-with-xetex/)

Comment: @Bugbusters: For Japanese, there is [pTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ptex) which do vertical typesetting well. There're also Korean packages, but I'm not familar with them.

Comment: Then when do we need to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{CJKutf8}`? And what is the difference between using `\usepackage{CJK}... \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}...\end{CJK}` and  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{CJKutf8}...\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}...\end{CJK}`?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: For CJK typesetting, there is no difference. `inputenc` with `utf8` option is useful when you typeset é, ü, etc. in other languages, such as French, Germen.

Comment: Sorry. Assume I don't use other languages as what you explained above so I don't use `utf8` input encoding, which in turn I don't use `CJKutf8` package but I just use `CJK` package. My question is why do we need to specify `UTF8` as the second argument of `CJK` environment?

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood: There are various character encodings used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean. UTF-8 encoding is just one of them. `CJK` package need to know the encoding of the source file to process the CJK characters properly.