# What is UpTex / UpLaTeX?

Tags: uplatex

Can someone please explain in more details what UpTeX / UpLaTeX really is?

I can only find japanese documenation about it.

I knew some ways to type CJK-fonts and directions with TeX and its engines but never heard of UpTeX before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the *Unicode* version of `pTeX` (`pLaTeX`), a japanese version of TeX (LaTeX). In difference to `pTeX` it can use all unicode characters:

**Edit**: OpenType fonts (such as Hiragino, Kozuka) can be used also with `pTeX`. Actually, `pTeX` and `upTeX` do nothing about fonts; whether a font can be used with them depends on `dvipdfmx`.

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{utarticle} % dvipdfmx driver option (for color) required, for post-processing of dvipdfmx
\usepackage{color} % not required for this example...
\begin{document}
\section{芥川龍之介「るしへる」}
破提宇子と云う天主教を弁難した書物のある事は、知っている人も少くあるまい。これは、元和六年、加賀の禅僧巴毗弇なるものの著した書物である。巴毗弇は当初南蛮寺に住した天主教徒であったが、その後何かの事情から、DS 如来を捨てて仏門に帰依する事になった。書中に云っている所から推すと、彼は老儒の学にも造詣のある、一かどの才子だったらしい。

\section{樋口一葉「大つごもり」}
お母樣御機嫌よう好い新年をお迎へなされませ、左樣ならば參りますと、暇乞わざと恭しく、お峰下駄を直せ、お玄關からお歸りではないお出かけだぞとづぶ〳〵しく大手を振りて、行先は何處、父が涙は一夜の   [...]

\end{document}
```

You have to run the example with `uplatex` which creates a `dvi` output which then has to be convert into a `pdf` with `dvipdfmx`:

[image]

And, of course, it is easier to use as `xelatex` with the `cjk` packages. More information is available from http://www.t-lab.opal.ne.jp/tex/uptex_en.html

Comment: This looks really nice.  However, I wonder if the Japanese actually use arabic numerals.

Comment: @HenriMenke: you mean `1` and so on? Yes, they do.

Comment: Great, never heard of it before. And the 1 million $ question: Is there a nice and easy way to write Kanji with furigana (Hiragano on top/right of it)? I only now the `\ruby` solution from XeLaTex.

Comment: I Never used it. Have a look into the manual

Comment: I'm a Japanese, and I prefer upLaTeX to XeLaTeX for two reasons: first, XeTeX doesn't support vertical writing, but upTeX does. Second, horizontal writing of upTeX is also more beautiful than that of XeTeX, as upTeX engine itself supports many features required for Japanese typesetting. You can use  `\ruby` from pxrubrica.sty in upTeX and pTeX, which is available from CTAN.

Comment: And, yes, we Japanese use both arabic numeral and Kanji numeral. When we place arabic numerals in vertical writing, there are two ways; in some case we rotate them clockwise (for example, "DS" and "Diabolus" in the example above are rotated; similar for arabic numeral). In other case numbers are placed as so-called "ren-suji" (section numbers  `1` and `2` above are ren-suji). Whether numbers are placed as "ren-suji" or not depends on tradition.

Comment: What is about [Furigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana)? Can `upLaTeX` handle this, too?

Comment: @buhtzsaysgetvaccinated Regarding Furigana, you can use "pxrubrica" package.