# How to install platex.exe (Japanese) in Tex Live. Re:Tex2img

Tags: languages

I'd like to use Tex2img.  As an option it creates svg output, but it appears to be looking for platex.exe (Japanese, not Polish) to do this.

When I installed Tex Live I chose a "medium" installation.  platex.exe does not exist (nor does uplatex.exe).   It's not obvious which package in the Tex Live Manager I need.  Which package do I need?

or:  how can I install platex.exe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tlmgr info`  to see which package

I get

```
 tlmgr info ptex
package:     ptex
category:    Package
shortdesc:   A TeX system for publishing in Japanese
longdesc:    PTeX adds features related to vertical writing, and deals with other problems in typesetting Japanese. A set of additions to a TEXMF tree, for use with PTeX, may be found in package PTeX-texmf. PTeX is distributed as WEB change files.
installed:   Yes
revision:    46954
sizes:       doc: 89k, bin: 3653k
relocatable: No
cat-date:    2018-01-06 12:14:59 +0100
cat-license: other-free
cat-topics:  engine japanese
collection:  collection-langjapanese
```

So you could install the ptex and platex packages or the whole of collection-langjapanese

Comment: Thank you.  However,  I had looked for a package called "ptex" using the GUI Tex Live Manager, but the GUI manager does not display a package with that name.  But typing "tlmgr install ptex" installs something.  But there is still no platex.exe on my system. This is not a critical issue for me, so I don't want to waste anyone's time.

Comment: @garyp The question here seems to be derived from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323682/accessing-platex-with-texniccenter/323795#comment1059877_323795 ; I added a comment there, please refer to it (it’s off-topic there, so we should proceed here)

Comment: I started this thread because that thread was specifically about TeXnicenter, but my question is focused on Tex2Img.  I'm not sure where to continue!  Perhaps both, but if I get to a specific working answer, I will post it here.

Comment: @garyp I have never used ptex (except in tests) or tex2img so I have answered all I can, sorry. If you want Hironobu to see your comment you would need to `@` ping

Comment: Whoops.  I forgot to ping @HironobuYAMASHITA Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @garyp Have you tried “tlmgr install platex” as well?