# Vertical, Right-to-Left Text

Tags: xetex, lyx, right-to-left, text

I'm writing a document in Chinese, and was wondering if there's a way to write text vertically, from right-to-left. There are several examples of what I mean on this page: [Wikipedia: Horizontal and Vertical Writing in East Asian Scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_and_vertical_writing_in_East_Asian_scripts)

I'm using LyX, but I have edited the preamble and worked with ERT before, so anything involving these is not a problem.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Note: Just to add, part of the document is also in English, so any method to change the text to vertical and right-to-left would have to be something which could be turned on and off.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295414/4778

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this in one document, so you might have to typeset the Chinese section separately. But you might want to look more into `uplatex` documentation and see if something can be done.

Comment: @Alenanno, thank you very much for the tip! For some reason, this didn't come up in my searches as a possible solution. At first, it didn't seem like there was a way to make the text horizontal using UpTeX/UpLaTeX, but then when I looked at some of the examples here: http://www.t-lab.opal.ne.jp/tex/uptex_en.html -- they did show some with horizontal text and others with vertical. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I would suggest using p(la)tex or up(la)tex, the Japanese variants that support vertical typesetting out of the box.