# How to create a node with a vertical Chinese text

Tags: tikz-pgf, ctex

I want to create a node with Chinese text written in vertical direction.  Of course, I don't want the characters to be rotated!  Is that possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner sep=2pt] at (0,0) {文章内容。};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I am using `PdfLaTeX` and I need only a couple of short vertical text nodes that will fit into a single column.

Comment: a handrawn sketch of the output would be helpful

Comment: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29hamano.pdf

Answer (score 4):

**Please use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX!**

[image: output]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{expl3}
\setmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \__map_function #1 {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\noindent #1 \par}
}

\cs_new:Npn \__map_function_centering #1 {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\centering #1 \par}
}

\newcommand{\verticaltext}[1]{
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \str_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_str \__map_function
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\newcommand{\verticalcentertext}[1]{
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \str_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_str \__map_function_centering
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner sep=2pt,text width=7mm] at (0,0) {\verticaltext{文章内容。}};
\node[draw,inner sep=2pt,text width=7mm] at (1,0) {\verticaltext{abcde}};
\node[draw,inner sep=2pt,text width=7mm] at (2,0) {\verticalcentertext{文章内容。}};
\node[draw,inner sep=2pt,text width=7mm] at (3,0) {\verticalcentertext{abcde}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have 10000 lines of LaTeX that compile well in MikTeX. Could it be done in MikTeX?

Comment: @Pygmalion MikTeX, just like TexLive are TeX distributions, which both contain XeTeX, LuaTeX (various TeX engines). Usually most CJK documents are compiled with XeTeX and LuaTeX, because they have native Unicode support. PDFLaTeX, however, doesn't support this feature. You can try running the code snippet above to see if results can be reproduced correctly. If you are using PDFLaTeX, maybe you can consider switching to XeTeX/LuaTeX.

Comment: @Pygmalion If you are using PDFLaTeX, and the need of vertical text is small, I think you can do it manually by entering `\noindent 文 \par \noindent 章 \par`... , which would be fairly easy to generate if you know other programming languages.

Comment: Yes, I am using PdfLaTeX and I am kind of reluctant to switch to XeLaTeX for only a few vertical nodes.  However `\noident \par` combination does not work.

Comment: Another question: with XeLaTeX I could actually use any font.  That would be a big plus.

Comment: @Pygmalion Did you set `text width`? It is necessary to specify a width for line breaks inside nodes to work.

Comment: @Pygmalion XeLaTeX allows one to load any OpenType/TrueType fonts.

Comment: @Pygmalion Note that `\centering 文 \par \centering 章 \par` gives horizontally centered text.

Answer (score 4):

A XeLaTeX approach, note that this is a pseudo vertical typesetting.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\tikzset{
  pseudo vertical/.style={
    % 1\ccwd is the width of one Chinese character, see user manual of ctex pkg
    text width=1\ccwd,
    % reduce line spacing and allow linebreak before Chinese period punct (。)
    % c.f. user manual of xeCJK pkg
    font=\linespread{1}\selectfont\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{CJK}{`。}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, inner sep=2pt, pseudo vertical] at (0,0) {文章内容。};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested this with `PdfLaTeX` and it actually works apart for the point.  Maybe I can avoid points altogether.

Comment: @Pygmalion I'm on macOS, and `ctex` doesn't support `pdflatex` on macOS (since the upstream package `CJK` relies on Chinese system fonts available on Windows only). Sorry I cannot test the pdflatex approach for you.

Answer (score 3):

I can't read or write Chinese, then I don't know if this is the right way to write it.

I just specified a width to the text `text width=1.5em` so that each character is displayed one under the other.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner sep=2pt,text width=1.5em] at (0,0) {文章内容。};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had this idea myself, but the result is very unaesthetically.

Comment: Without having an example of the rendering you want, only people who can read and write Chinese can answer you.

Comment: Make it `text width=1em` or something relative so that the Chinese period is on its own line.

Comment: @Symbol1 According to my tests, it takes at least `1.5em`

Comment: Thanks. I would have never knew how `em` works with Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

You can use system fonts, like the Noto series. That way you are not tied to particular font packages for specific systems.

This variation of an answer uses tikz `positioning`, so useful for short texts.

[image: vert zh]

Compile with xelatex\lualatex.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\zhfont[Scale=2.5,Colour=blue]{Noto Serif SC}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\ \marginpar{
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=3pt,node distance=0mm,font={\zhfont}]
  \node (a) {文};
  \node (b) [below=of a] {章};
  \node (c) [below=of b] {内};
  \node (d) [below=of c] {容};
  \node (e) [below=of d] {。};
\end{tikzpicture}} \lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum:

Alternatively, question [Vertical Chinese text with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38577/vertical-chinese-text-with-xetex/38585#38585) provides a 'rotate the glyphs' solution for fonts with the feature.
The minipage box they are in is also rotated, so the characters come out vertical.

[image: vertical]

This could be adapted to tikz.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setCJKfamilyfont{songvert}[RawFeature={vertical;+vert},Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{Noto Serif SC}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}% do not modify the spacing between punctuations
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKsymbol}

\newcommand\sampletext{『文章内容』。}

\begin{document}

\sampletext\  This is some sample text.
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{-90}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{10em}
\CJKfamily{songvert}\CJKmove
\sampletext \\
\sampletext \\
\sampletext \\
\sampletext \\
\end{minipage}}}
\end{center}
\sampletext\  This is some sample text.

\end{document}
```

---

A tikz node inline, containing rotated glyphs and their box:

[image: vertical inline]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setCJKfamilyfont{songvert}[RawFeature={vertical;+vert},Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{Noto Serif SC}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}% do not modify the spacing between punctuations
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKsymbol}

\newcommand\sampletext{『文章内容』。}

\begin{document}

\sampletext\  This is some sample text.
\tikz \node {\rotatebox{-90}{\colorbox{red!4}{
\CJKfamily{songvert}\CJKmove
\sampletext}}};
\sampletext\  This is some sample text.

\end{document}
```