# How to make two column of letters

Tags: tables, align, calligraphy

I am editing a book cover, but I don't know how to make two columns of letters (in LaTeX environment). The size of letters in two columns are different. (I show it in the photo below).

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You could use this question as a starting point: [How to create a node with a vertical Chinese text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555700/123129).

Comment: @dexteritas, I use https://www.overleaf.com/  to  work with my document.  Unfortunately, your method  you provide via the link doesn't work .  Maybe I'm  very green !!

Comment: Since I don't know Chinese text, are the characters oriented in the normal vertical configuration or have they been rotated 90 degrees?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes They are in the normal vertical configuration !

Comment: Perhaps something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{a b c d e} {\LARGE\Shortstack{f g h i j k}}
\end{document}`